# How I setup flow of multiple tenant in azure ad asp.net core (itfoxtec)

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

If you have any sample example of multiple tenants in azure ad with itfoxtec library then please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Each Azure AD tenant (Azure AD enterprise application) have a unique issuer, endpoint and SAML 2.0 metadata. Therefore, you need a configuration for each tenant in your application implementing ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2. The configuration for each tenant can be loaded by calling each Azure AD enterprise application's SAML 2.0 metadata endpoint.

You can assign each tenant a unique return points in your application and thereby you know which configuration to use.

I do not have a simple sample. I have created [FoxIDs](https://foxids.doc) which support Azure AD multiple tenants with both OpenID Connect ([Stack Overflow description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543161/is-it-possible-to-connect-foxids-to-azure-ad-with-openid-connect/66544212#66544212)) and SAML 2.0, It is [open source](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/FoxIDs) at you are welcome to look at the code. However, the code does include many other things.

Comment: Did not understand. Can you brief again?

Comment: Can you please provide POC ( or suggest implementation )  to load the configuration for each unique return endpoint? that will be great help  in the current sample project, SAML configuration loaded once while application startup.